# ActionView::Template::Error: while running rspec in groups or file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I am working on view specs using RSpec. When I use render in it block. Then my first test case is passed but 2nd one is saying the error.

```
Failure/Error: render
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `__abc_edit_html_erb___2948629399434343193_79820' for #<#<Class:0x000000000a357488>:0x000000000a3553b8>
```

```
it "displays the correct text Editing Device" do
  render
  expect(rendered).to match t('device.edit')
end

it "should have form" do 
  render
  assert_select "form"
end
```